# Encode string to another base with more characters?

Tags: string, encoding, compression, radix

I know that I can [encode numbers to a base like 65](https://github.com/Xeoncross/micromvc/blob/master/system/cipher.php#L58) to decrease the size of the character display (even if the number is smaller in binary).

**However, is there a way to encode UTF-8 text to another base with more characters than our standard 26 letter English alphabet?** In other words, Instead of requiring 4 "characters" for the word "four" - I can create a representation or hash using only, maybe 2 (i.e. "6$")?

Comment: Are you asking whether an arbitrary four-character UTF8 string can be losslessly represented in two bytes?

Comment: Actually @aix, I'm asking if I can compress an arbitrary 2-30 character string (a word) so it takes less space than our standard 26 character alphabet requires. Like zipping or hashing can create a representative of a value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the point of Base64 is you can easily convert any binary data into "human readable" letters and numbers.  It makes it easy to transcribe arbitrary data to newsgroups or transmit them over text based protocols.

If you want to further "compress" this data, you need to figure out how many characters you want to allow.  There's only so many combinations of 8 bits.  The most efficient would be to use all of them, in which case why just not use gzip?

Comment: I would be happy to use gzip if there was some way to represent the values in a human readable way (without decompressing each gzip'ed value) and also compare the gzip values to others. You can see an example of converting something like the number 4,023 to "~h" in the code I linked to above.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems related to Order-0 entropy coding :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_encoding

The most famous algorithm is this family is Huffman coding :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Huffman will not only tells you that only 64 characters are used and therefore only 6 bits per characters are necessary : it will also make a difference between frequent characters, such as (space), and rare ones, such as (;). It will then create a code in which frequent characters use less bits than rarer ones, resulting in better compression (typically 4.5bits per character on English texts).

Huffman coding is an all-around compression technique, used as part of many compression algorithms, including zip.
You can find a demo program which only applies one pass of Huffman compression here (Huff0), it will help you determine how much can be gained by using this technique for your sample inputs :
http://fastcompression.blogspot.com/p/huff0-range0-entropy-coders.html